# Is it possible to pass GET parameters in a redirect and not showing them in url?

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have searched a lot but cannot find any way to hide GET parameters in url which were passed to a redirect in symfony2.

Comment: nothing impossible, especially in your case... what u done sofar....

Comment: no, get parameters are always in the url. you could use an iframe though.

Comment: instead of GET use POST.  GET cannot be hide.

Comment: @JithinVarghese I am doing post/redirect/get  and passing parameters in redirect, is there any way to pass post parameters in redirect?

Answer (score 0):

GET parameters cannot be hide.

GET HTTP method does not imply any body in HTTP request so all the parameters must be defined in URI.

Comment: Actually, it's perfectly valid (though very unusual) to pass parameters in a GET body.  Of course it doesn't really hide anything since the data is still being passed to the browser but it can be done.